# Is it possible to move Zoom Controls to a different location on Screen in OSMdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm looking at moving default zoom controls of osmdroid to a different position. Is it possible to do this? If so, can anyone point me how?

I tried digging deep, through much of stackoverflow but no result. Or should I go with customizing by creating a custom zoom controls again for my app?

My intention is to relocate the already available zoom controls to a different place on screen.

Comment: move to what position? can you be clearer about what you want?

Comment: I want to shift the zoom controls to a different location on screen.

Comment: you have to do your own custom controls

Comment: I want to know since they have already done it in API, can there be a work around to do it.

Comment: check out https://github.com/johnjohndoe/OSMDroidOfflineDemo

Comment: and http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/osmdroid-and-zoom-control.35851/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot relocate the `MapView`'s integrated zoom control using the OSMDroid API.

The only way to do that without modifying the library's source code is to implement a `FrameLayout` over your `MapView` and that will include the controls you wish, where you wish. This also allows you to customize them (by showing a slider for example).

Once this done, you should ensure that `MapView.setBuiltInZoomControls()` is set to `false`.

Comment: That means, I must use the custom zoom control in order to gain full accessibility.

Comment: Without modifying the lib, yes. Another interesting way forward is to modify the lib and to submit your changes to OSMDroid. This way they will be useful to everybody!